# Need Javascript Regex to prevent user to enter only characters and only one apostrophe allowed

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I need Javascript regex, to prevent user to enter anything and only characters and only one apostrophe allowed.

**Allowed** -
Dsouza's, Test's

**Not Allowed** : 
test''s , test'''1s

I am using below regex to prevent user to enter numbers and special characters. I need to allow only one apostrophe in between characters.

```
/[^A-Za-z]/g
```

My requirement is to use regex like below snippet.

```
function fromUser(model) {
            var preset = {

                'only-letters': /[^A-Za-z]/g

            };
            var regex = preset[attr.customInputValidator] || attr.customInputValidator;
            var transformedInput = model.replace(regex, '');


            return transformedInput; 
}
```

Comment: A-A? That does not look right either. Also, you seem to try to match violations instead of matching valid entries.

Comment: @trincot Edited.

Comment: Yep, see @trincot’s edit: the first step is going to be to change this negative check for a bad character into a positive check for a string containing only good characters.

Comment: Need to perform this activity in replace function. So only characters and one apostrophe is allowed in between those characters.

Comment: @Suhas: How are you allowing `Dsouza's` when you have negated alphabets? I thought you wanted to allow only alphabets one or more and just one apostrophe optionally in between them. Let me know if I am correct or provide more valid/invalid samples.

Comment: @PushpeshKumarRajwanshi I wanted to allow apostrophe in between characters that also only one. I didnt find solution thats why I asked here. Need Regex for this.

Comment: Please show how you’re using the existing regex; “in replace function” isn’t clear. Also, do you need to allow at most one apostrophe between characters, or one apostrophe in the whole word/something else?

Comment: edited please check

Comment: Would "O'Reighly's" be allowed? What about a hyphen: "John-Martin", or a space "John Frederick", or accents "Sébastien", "Müller", "Åke", "Løvik", ...etc...etc.

Answer (score 1):

This a example hope it will help you. use pattern:  **`/^(?!.*'.*'.*)[a-zA-Z']+$/`**

```js
var strings = [
     "Dsouza",
     "Dsouza's",
      "Dsouza's",
       "Dsouza''s",
       "test''s ",
       "test'''1s"
] , html = '';

for ( var i = 0; i< strings.length ; i++ ){  
    html += ''+[ 
            'sring : <b>'+strings[i] + '</b>'     
           , 'using regx :<b>' + ( /^(?!.*'.*'.*)[a-zA-Z']+$/.test(strings[i]) ) + '</b>'
    ].join('<br />') + '<br /><br />';
}

document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = html ;
```

```html
<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: what is for `Dsouza's  Dsouza''s` ?

Answer (score 0):

For allowing only alphabets and only one occurrence of apostrophe and even that could be optional, you may use this regex,

```
^[a-zA-Z]+(?:'[a-zA-Z]+)?$
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/doVR43/2)

This matches either purely alphabet characters, or matches alphabets containing only one apostrophe within the alphabets.

Let me know if this suits your requirements, else I can further modify based upon your further examples of valid/invalid data sets.

Answer (score 0):

To allow only alphabets and one special character('), use this RegEx, with two variation:

1. Allowing this pattern `asd'sad`

   ```
   /^[A-Z]+(?:'?[A-Z]+)?$/i.test("asdgrr'ssde"); // true
   /^[A-Z]+(?:'?[A-Z]+)?$/i.test("asdgrr's");    // true
   /^[A-Z]+(?:'?[A-Z]+)?$/i.test("AGTrr'ssde");  // true
   /^[A-Z]+(?:'?[A-Z]+)?$/i.test("asdssde");     // true
   /^[A-Z]+(?:'?[A-Z]+)?$/i.test("arr'ss'de");   // false
   ```
2. Allowing only one alphabet after ' i.e. `asd's`:

   ```
   /^[A-Z]+(?:'?[A-Z])?$/i.test("asdgrr'ssde"); // false
   /^[A-Z]+(?:'?[A-Z])?$/i.test("asdgrr's");    // true
   /^[A-Z]+(?:'?[A-Z])?$/i.test("asdgrr'S");    // true
   /^[A-Z]+(?:'?[A-Z])?$/i.test("ATRr'g");      // true
   /^[A-Z]+(?:'?[A-Z])?$/i.test("AGTrr'ssde");  // false
   /^[A-Z]+(?:'?[A-Z])?$/i.test("asdssde");     // true
   /^[A-Z]+(?:'?[A-Z])?$/i.test("arr'ss'de");   // false
   ```